# OpenVPN Client WebUI fail after installing OpenVPN AS

Tags: vpn, openvpn, authentication, ubuntu-16.04

I just installed OpenVPN on ubuntu 16.04. After installing, I can access the Admin WebUI and login with user openvpn. None of the Client login works.I just get the message "**Login failed**".
[image]

In the Log Reports on the admin page I see the following error logged.

```
     - rolf-PE-860  
        - oclient   
        - 06/09/19 00:23        
        - WEB_CLIENT    
        - 192.168.10.215                        
        - local auth failed: no stored password digest found in authcred attributes:
    auth/authlocal:35,web/http:1609,web/http:750,web/server:127,we
/server:134,xml/authrpc:110,xml/authrpc:164,internet/defer:102,xml

/authsess:50,sagent/saccess:86,xml/authrpc:244,xml/authsess:50,xml

/authsess:103,auth/authdelegate:308,util/delegate:26,auth/authdelegate:237,util

/defer:224,util/defer:246,internet/defer:190,internet/defer:181,internet

/defer:323,util/defer:246,internet/defer:190,internet/defer:181,internet

/defer:323,util/defer:245,internet/defer:102,auth/authdelegate:61,auth

/authdelegate:240,util/delegate:26,auth/authlocal:35,util/error:61,util/error:44
```

Can someone help me understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

After some reading of documentation, I found reference to the Auth CLI. Getting access to this enabled me to see the missing link in the conf and address this.

Rolf